# Attaching Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control to Excel file

Tags: vba, date

I am currently using ***Microsoft Date and Time Picker*** Control on my Excel file and it works fine on my computer. But when I send it to someone, it says they're missing the file.

> My question is whether it is possible to install it for the user
>   automatically so it does not say the control is missing from their
>   computer?

This is for a school project that maximizes the user experience, therefore I would need it to be simple and easy to setup.

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` is part of the ActiveX `MSCOMCT2.OCX`. This family of ActiveX are 32bits exclusively and won't work on 64bits versions of Excel.

Comment: @VincentG That's no longer the case, there's a 64-bit version of the controls available and, if I've understood what I've heard correctly, is even part of an automatic update for 64-bit Office 365 subscribers.  The name of the control mscomct2.ocx.

Comment: @CindyMeister Missed this news. I will have to test it. What took them so long?

Comment: @VincentG Apparently, it's been around for 9 months or so...